# Convert column names into row values and find sum

Tags: r

I have this data frame-

```
input_output <- data.frame(ip_op = c('input_0', 'input_2', 'input_9', 'output_1', 'output_2', 'output_3'), a = c(1,32, 12, 246, 901, 837), b = c(284, 23, 19, 284, 9, 12), c = c(12, 8940, 379, 490, 0, 12))

ip_op   a   b    c
1  input_0   1 284   12
2  input_2  32  23 8940
3  input_9  12  19  379
4 output_1 246 284  490
5 output_2 901   9    0
6 output_3 837  12   12
```

I want to create the following data frame-

```
input_output
  type input output
1    a    45   1984
2    b   326    305
3    c  9331    502
```

I have tried using `transpose` but the column names become rownames. How do I transform this data frame?

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)    
> input_output %>% pivot_longer(-ip_op) %>% mutate(ip_op = str_extract(ip_op, ('input|output'))) %>% group_by(ip_op, name) %>% summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
+  pivot_wider(names_from = ip_op, values_from = value) %>% rename(type = name)
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'ip_op' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  type  input output
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a        45   1984
2 b       326    305
3 c      9331    502
>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try reshaping data to long, then separate the variable name to keep the desired suffix. Aggregate the values with respective groups and then reshape to wide. Here the code using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
new <- input_output %>% pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  separate(ip_op,c('Var1','Var2'),sep='_') %>%
  select(-Var2) %>% group_by(Var1,name) %>%
  summarise(value=sum(value,na.rm = T)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var1,values_from=value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  input output
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a        45   1984
2 b       326    305
3 c      9331    502
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

input_output %>%
  mutate(ip_op = sub("_.*$", "", ip_op)) %>%
  group_by(ip_op) %>%
  summarise(across(a:c, ~sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)), .groups = "keep") %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = a:c,
    names_to = 'type',
    values_to = 'value'
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = type,
    names_from = ip_op,
    values_from = value
  )
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  type  input output
#  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 a        45   1984
#2 b       326    305
#3 c      9331    502
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `aggregate` + `reshape` like below

```
u <- aggregate(
  . ~ ip_op,
  transform(
    input_output,
    ip_op = gsub("_\\d+", "", ip_op)
  ),
  sum
)

reshape(
  cbind(stack(u[-1]), type = u$ip_op),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "ind",
  timevar = "type"
)
```

which gives

```
  ind values.input values.output
1   a           45          1984
3   b          326           305
5   c         9331           502
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(input_output), id.var = 'ip_op',
 variable.name = 'type')[, ip_op := sub("_.*", "", ip_op)], 
   type ~ ip_op, value.var = 'value', sum)
```

-output

```
#   type input output
#1:    a    45   1984
#2:    b   326    305
#3:    c  9331    502
```

---

Or using `transpose`

```
data.table::transpose(setDT(input_output)[, ip_op := sub("_\\d+$", "", ip_op)][,
      lapply(.SD, sum), ip_op], make.names = 'ip_op', keep.names = 'type')
```

-output

```
#   type input output
#1:    a    45   1984
#2:    b   326    305
#3:    c  9331    502
```

---

Or with `tidyverse` and `data.table::transpose`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
input_output %>%
    group_by(ip_op = str_remove(ip_op, '_\\d+$')) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    data.table::transpose(make.names = 'ip_op', keep.names = 'type')
#  type input output
#1    a    45   1984
#2    b   326    305
#3    c  9331    502
```